# How to fix a Samsung with Android 8.0 and 8.1.0 specific SecurityException when calling AudioManager.setMode(MODE_NORMAL)?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, permissions, samsung-mobile

I am working on an app which uses the AudioManager for changing the audio state. While the app is in background the app crashes when changing the mode back to normal.

It is a device specific problem. It happens only on Samsung devices with Android 8.0 or Android 8.1.0 while the app is in background.

I've tried changing the mode of the AudioManager while the app is background with bluetooth headphones using the specific samsung devices. Samsung Galaxy s8+ for example. I wasn't able to reproduce this, but there are plenty of Crashlytics reported crashes.

This is what causes the crash:

```
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

This is what the crash:

```
Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10240 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.
    android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1967)
    android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1913)
    android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.setMode (IAudioService.java:1683)
    android.media.AudioManager.setMode (AudioManager.java:2142)
```

Comment: Add the `BLUETOOTH` permission to your app, apparently. That should not be needed, since you are not hitting any Bluetooth APIs, but you may not have a choice given that stack trace.

Comment: Adding BLUETOOTH permissions is a bit too much just for these types of devices. I do not see how I can explain to the user that he should grant BLUETOOTH permission when the app doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a run time permission issue whenever you're dealing with latest android versions always provide runtime permissions hence to solve this simply provide run time permissions in your app

Answer (score 0):

Add Bluetooth Permission in your manifest file.